# SOAP Error : rg.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have working with SOAP in yii2 and I got an error when I tried to process a soap call

This my soap request :

```
$xmlInput = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ws=\"http://ws.api.interfaces.sessions.uams.amdocs\" xmlns:util=\"http://utils.uams.amdocs\" xmlns:web=\"http://webservices.fw.jf.amdocs\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ws:createUser><ws:aCreateUserInfo><util:userId>" . strtoupper($Userid) . "</util:userId><util:effDate>" . $Effdate . "T00:00:09+07:00</util:effDate><util:expDate>" . $Expdate . "T00:00:09+07:00</util:expDate><util:password>" . $this->randomPassword(8) . "</util:password><util:userRoles><ws:item>" . $Role . "</ws:item></util:userRoles></ws:aCreateUserInfo><ws:_awsi_header><web:securedTicket>" . $Ticket . "</web:securedTicket></ws:_awsi_header></ws:createUser></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Finally I got a response like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode><faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.</faultstring><detail><faultData><cause xsi:nil="true"/><exception xsi:nil="true"/><message>SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.</message></faultData><ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ocsbrntapp4</ns1:hostname></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Anybody can help me to fix this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading SOAP UI and do a request from there. You will easily be able to see what you are missing.

https://www.soapui.org/downloads/latest-release.html

SOAP UI will automatically tell you exactly what the xml should look like when you post to web service so it is very easy to see where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably caused by incorrect escaped xml file.
please examine **$xmlInput**

Based on your code, I would assome that the problem is inside your **"$this->randomPassword(8)"** function, but without seeing this function I am just asuming.

if you output $xmlInput and see illegal xml characters in there, you can escape them in 2 ways.

1) `$xmlInput = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ws=\"http://ws.api.interfaces.sessions.uams.amdocs\" xmlns:util=\"http://utils.uams.amdocs\" xmlns:web=\"http://webservices.fw.jf.amdocs\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ws:createUser><ws:aCreateUserInfo><util:userId>" . strtoupper($Userid) . "</util:userId><util:effDate>" . $Effdate . "T00:00:09+07:00</util:effDate><util:expDate>" . $Expdate . "T00:00:09+07:00</util:expDate><util:password><![CDATA[" . htmlentities($this->randomPassword(8), ENT_XHTML, 'UTF-8') . "]]></util:password><util:userRoles><ws:item>" . $Role . "</ws:item></util:userRoles></ws:aCreateUserInfo><ws:_awsi_header><web:securedTicket>" . $Ticket . "</web:securedTicket></ws:_awsi_header></ws:createUser></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";`

2) `$xmlInput = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ws=\"http://ws.api.interfaces.sessions.uams.amdocs\" xmlns:util=\"http://utils.uams.amdocs\" xmlns:web=\"http://webservices.fw.jf.amdocs\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ws:createUser><ws:aCreateUserInfo><util:userId>" . strtoupper($Userid) . "</util:userId><util:effDate>" . $Effdate . "T00:00:09+07:00</util:effDate><util:expDate>" . $Expdate . "T00:00:09+07:00</util:expDate><util:password><![CDATA[" . $this->randomPassword(8) . "]]></util:password><util:userRoles><ws:item>" . $Role . "</ws:item></util:userRoles></ws:aCreateUserInfo><ws:_awsi_header><web:securedTicket>" . $Ticket . "</web:securedTicket></ws:_awsi_header></ws:createUser></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";`

Basically check the contents of $xmlInput and, make sure that all values are escaped properly.